# ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row returns wrong row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a small macro to add and delete rows in a protected worksheet. For this each line has a "Delete" button. When a new line is added, the last existing line is copied (including the "Delete" button) and then its content is cleared.

For deleting the rows I hand over some parameters including the "Delete" button's (and thus the item's) row. For this I use:

```
RowToDelete = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
```

This code works fine for existing lines, but it will fail for all lines added since the workbook was last opened (except for the last one). For all other it will delete the next line that was added instead of the "real" one.

I guess that this is a cache problem, as the "Application.Caller" contains the right string, but returns the row of the copied shape that no longer carries that name.

Is there a way to clear the relevant cache or to force Shapes() to not use the cache?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: when you are creating your shapes give them the name (name property) of the row they are attached to. for any row added in between the existing ones just run a loop down to the last row and change their names adding +1 to the numeric part of the shape

Comment: That's more or less what I do, the problem is, that "ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row will return the row of the wrong shape. Lets say we started with Row A and Shape1 and add 2 rows B and C with Shape2 (a copy of Shape1) and Shape3 (a copy of Shape2) then the above code will return the row of Shape3 instead of Shape2 if Shape2 is clicked.

Comment: if your button is an ActiveX control, it won't be deleted on the same time as the row deletes (add a `ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).delete` in that case).  with Form control button, the button is automatically deleted on the same time than the row.   what i'm saying, is you might have several buttons stacking on the same position (old buttons as well)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround that I'm not too happy with but has to do the trick for now. I'm using random shapenames to avoid the wrong return values. It seems that if the shape name did not exist before the lookup works.

```
shp.Name = "Shape" & Format(i, "0000") & (Rnd * 999)
```

Must be some cache problem, as the button work fine after saving and reopening the workbook.

Comment: if it were a cache problem, a simple save before try would do the trick, or the artillery method : save, close, reopen, try.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The buttons were created by other buttons like yours. However, it only started doing it when in the code that creates the buttons, I started adding a name to it. So another not so satisfying way of dealing with it is to just not have the "shp.name= " line. When I took that out it stopped doing it. My guess is that  in the natural way of naming buttons it naturally avoids that. Just like when you have a sheet, delete it, and add another sheet, it still remembers the old sheet and names the new sheet a higher number.
A code to delete the cache would be nice. I am sure somebody knows how to do that if the question was asked differently. Searching for that gives:
Application.Restart()
I haven't tried it though.