# Application.Caller returning incorrect row number

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
With b.TopLeftCell
    bcn = .Column
    brn = .Row
End With
```

Most of the time it works flawlessly. However, sometimes when this is called the row number returned is off by +14. There are no hidden rows in the sheet.
When this happens, if you leave the worksheet open for several minutes and do nothing, it will start working again.

What is happening, how can I fix it, or is there a better way to get the row number?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/16668705/11683 help?

Comment: These things don't tend to spontaneously change.  The only thing I can suggest is `ActiveSheet` may not be what you expect.

Comment: I use `Application.Caller.Row` to get the row...

Comment: @Dean That does not help when `Application.Caller` is [the name of the clicked button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller#remarks).

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? as in, why do you need this row number? maybe there is anther more stable way to achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this was happening was due to multiple buttons on top of each other. Occasionally, a background button (that shouldn't have been there at all) became the foreground button and was the source of the unexpected behaviour. Removing the duplicate buttons solved the problem.

This only became apparent when trying to programmatically rename buttons, which manifested by trying to give multiple buttons the same name and a permission denied error raised, as the name was based on row and column number.

The issue only happened about 1 in every ~20 opens so it was not a big enough problem to cause major concern; hence why it took 6 months to solve.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that if you leave the default name on your `Buttons`, it's quite probable that you'll have duplicate names and `Application.Caller` will just return a non-unique name, failing to return the correct `Sheet` name you need.

You can avoid this by using custom names and by renaming your `Buttons` with a naming convention, like `SheetName` + `Button` + `Counter` (e.g: `Sheet1Button1`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: `Application.Caller` is a button name only in the macro that was invoked by a click on that button. To click the button, the sheet it's located on must be active. There is no way to programmatically click a Shape button. Hence, `ActiveSheet` should be correct.

Comment: @GSerg I agree, but we don't have the full code and maybe the user has the time to switch document or to work on another `Sheet` (it happened to one of my clients). It's always good practice to specify `Workbook` and `Worksheet` in any case.

Comment: It's a problem in itself, because when you have buttons on several sheets, you [cannot know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57834431/get-the-worksheet-of-the-button-which-called-the-macro#comment102103265_57834431) which sheet the clicked button belongs to.

Comment: True, just tested on my Excel and if you create a button on another `Sheet`, by default Excel name it with the same name.

Comment: @GSerg: to get the sheet that the button belongs to, wouldn't you just use `ActiveSheet` as the button would always be on the active sheet.. as per your comments above